# How to summon mobs with player head

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been making an adventure map and I want to make an Orc with armor and a custom player head. I did it kind of like you do with `/give (/give @p skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:player you want}` I am just using my player's head as a placeholder for now. Instead of giving me a mob with player head it doesn't even summon the mob. I am using minecraft 1.12. The command:

```
/summon minecraft:zombie ~ ~1 ~ {LeftHanded:0,Health:20,Fire:0,HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:iron_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"Orc Sword",Lore:["Bloody and rusted..."]},ench:[{id:16,lvl:3},{id:22,lvl:3}]},Count:1},{}],HandDropChances:[2F,0F],ArmorItems:[{id:"minecraft:iron_boots",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:iron_leggings",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:iron_chestplate",Count:1},{id:"minecraft:skull",{SkullOwner:CandyCaneFeeder},Damage:3,tag:{display:{Name:"Orc Head",Lore:["A trophy of your success against an Orc!"]}},Count:1}],ArmorDropChances:[0F,0F,0F,0.94F]}
```

The mob head I'm hoping to use instead of placeholder:

```
/give @p skull 1 3 {display:{Name:"Orc"},SkullOwner:{Id:"aa9cfe76-e245-4e2b-9ee1-dc78e3b02137",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNWIzMWEzYjBlMjFlMjY1MDQ2NjljM2VlYmM4M2ViMjY2YWVmZGQ0NTZlN2UxZTQ3ZTM0MmQ5N2YwYmZhZjkifX19"}]}}}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Place the `SkullOwner` tag into the `tag` tag, where you also put the `display` tag.

Also you have some redundant tags, for example a newly spawned zombie always has `Health:20` and `Fire:0`.